# JPA composite key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have a table A which has a composite key, say columns A, B and C.
Another table B with some added fields (child of A) will share the primary key A,B,C
Basically when data is inserted in TABLE A, same copy will be there in C with some added information.
Tried Id class , join columns etc.
Sometimes broken id error comes or other .
Please check the structure and let me know if you can help.

```
      Class BIdClass
@Id
@Column(name="A")
private Integer a;

@Id
@Column(name="B")
private Integer b;

@Id
@Column(name="C")
private Integer c;

@Id
@OneToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="A", referencedColumnName="A"),
    @JoinColumn(name="B", referencedColumnName="B"),
    @JoinColumn(name="C", referencedColumnName="C)
})
private ClassA a;



    
@IdClass
Class B{

@Id
@Column(name="A")
private Integer a;

@Id
@Column(name="B")
private Integer b;

@Id
@Column(name="C")
private Integer c;

@MapsId("a")
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="A", referencedColumnName="A"),
    @JoinColumn(name="B", referencedColumnName="B ),
    @JoinColumn(name="C", referencedColumnName="C)
})
private ClassA a;
}



Class A{
@OneToOne(mappedBy="a",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private ClassB b;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to reformat your code example at it is super hard to understand like this. Try to make to code boxes, one for each class and then past valid Java code which makes reading and replicating a lot easier